# ARM / NEON assembly: proper way to test values

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I want to compare some values in ARM / NEON assembly.

Does the following code

```
if (d0 == 0) //the whole 64-bit
    r1 += 8;
else {
    if (d0[0] == 0) //the lower 8-bit
        r1 += 1;
    ...
}
....
```

corresponds to this:

```
vcmp.f64 d0, #0
vmrs APSR_nzcv, fpscr

addeq r1, r1, #8
beq .jumpover

vmov.u8 r0, d0[0]
cmp r0, #0
addeq r1, r1, #1
...

jumpover:
....
```

Similarly, does the following code

```
if (!(d0 == 0 && d1 == 0)) {//the whole 128-bit
    ...
}
....
```

corresponds to this:

```
vorr d2, d0, d1
vcmp.f64 d2, #0
vmrs APSR_nzcv, fpscr
beq .jumpover
...

jumpover:
....
```

Is there a way to improve the translation?

Comment: Looks to me like you need [`vclz`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801f/dom1361289948783.html) and possibly [`vrev64.8`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801f/dom1361289981418.html).  You want to do everything you can to avoid tests and branches like that.  Something like `vrev64.8 d0, d0`, `vclz.32 d0, d0`, `vmov.32 r0, r1, d0`, `cmp r0, #32`, `addeq r0, r0, r1`, `mov r0, r0, LSR #3`.

Comment: You probably want to consider this on a higher level, rather than statement-by-statement. You can't vectorise an `if` statement, and bouncing back and forth between vector and integer code really kills efficiency. Better to try and rework that entire part of the algorithm into something which can be expressed in terms of a vectorised conditional select operation.